# Can't pull my struct data to the main() function (C language)

Tags: c, function, gcc

I'm writing Matrix library , I have MatrixMultiplication(Mat a , Mat b) function that returns Mat

inside the function everything is working correctly but when I'm pulling it to the main all the calculation disappears , although I'm using pointers .

my **Mat struct** is using pointer to a **1d array** and **n** x **k** values for sizing.

---

**INPUT :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 
#define size 100
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////       ALL THIS FUNCTIONS WORK PERFECTLY       //////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int RandomRange(int l,int u){int a = (rand()%(u-l+1))+l;return a;}
void ArrayRandomizer(int *a ,int s,int l,int u){for(int i = 0; i < s; i++){
    int random = RandomRange(l,u);int *ptr2 = &random;Swap(a+i,ptr2);}}
typedef struct Mat {int * arr, rows, cols;} Mat;
Mat MatrixBuilder (int *a,int r,int c){Mat new;new.arr = a;new.rows = r;new.cols = c;return new;}
void PrintMatrix (Mat a){
    printf("\nMatrix %dx%d :\n",a.rows,a.cols);
    for (int i = 1, j = 0; i <= a.rows; i++ ,j = j + a.cols ){
    for (; j < (a.cols*a.rows); j++){
    if ((j+i)%a.cols == 1){printf(" [");}
    printf("%d ,",*(a.arr+(j+i-1)));
    if ((j+i)%a.cols == 0){printf("]\n");}}}}
int MatrixValueOfCell (Mat a,int r,int c){
    if (r > a.rows-1){printf("\n*****MatrixValueOfCell ROW IS OUT OF THE MATRIX , USE SMALLER INTEGER");return -9999999;}
    if (c > a.cols-1){printf("\n*****MatrixValueOfCell COL IS OUT OF THE MATRIX , USE SMALLER INTEGER");return -9999999;}
    if (r < 0){printf("\n*****MatrixValueOfCell CAN'T USE NEGATIVE ROW INDEX , USE BIGGER INTEGER");return -9999999;}
    if (c < 0){printf("\n*****MatrixValueOfCell CAN'T USE NEGATIVE COL INDEX , USE BIGGER INTEGER");return -9999999;}
    return *(a.arr+((r)*a.cols)+(c));}
void setMatrixValueOfCell (int s,Mat a,int r,int c){
    if (r > a.rows-1){printf("\n*****MatrixValueOfCell ROW IS OUT OF THE MATRIX , USE SMALLER INTEGER");}
    else if (c > a.cols-1){printf("\n*****MatrixValueOfCell COL IS OUT OF THE MATRIX , USE SMALLER INTEGER");}
    else if (r < 0){printf("\n*****MatrixValueOfCell CAN'T USE NEGATIVE ROW INDEX , USE BIGGER INTEGER");}
    else if (c < 0){printf("\n*****MatrixValueOfCell CAN'T USE NEGATIVE COL INDEX , USE BIGGER INTEGER");}
    else {*(a.arr+((r)*a.cols)+(c)) = s ;}}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Mat MatrixMultiplication (Mat a,Mat b){
int q [a.rows*b.cols]; int * ptr = q;
ArrayRandomizer(ptr,a.rows*b.cols,0,0);
Mat c = MatrixBuilder (ptr,a.rows,b.cols);
for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < b.cols; j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < a.cols; k++){
            setMatrixValueOfCell((MatrixValueOfCell(c,i,j)+(MatrixValueOfCell(a,i,k)*MatrixValueOfCell(b,k,j))),c,i,j);}}}

printf("\n________________________________\nDirect From Function :");
PrintMatrix(c);
printf("________________________________\n");
return c;

}



int main (void){

int a[size];ArrayRandomizer(a,size,0,46);int * ptr = a;
Mat test = MatrixBuilder(ptr , 4 , 3);

int b[size];ArrayRandomizer(b,size,0,9);int * ptr2 = b;
Mat test2 = MatrixBuilder(ptr2 , 3 , 4);

PrintMatrix(test);
PrintMatrix(test2);

Mat Result = MatrixMultiplication(test,test2);

PrintMatrix(Result);

}
```

---

---

**OUTPUT :**

```
Matrix 4x3 :
    [38 ,4 ,18 ,]
    [23 ,17 ,26 ,]
    [16 ,3 ,28 ,]
    [28 ,10 ,17 ,]

Matrix 3x4 :
    [5 ,0 ,4 ,8 ,]
    [7 ,1 ,7 ,2 ,]
    [7 ,2 ,2 ,6 ,]

________________________________
Direct From Function :
Matrix 4x4 :
    [344 ,40 ,216 ,420 ,]
    [416 ,69 ,263 ,374 ,]
    [297 ,59 ,141 ,302 ,]
    [329 ,44 ,216 ,346 ,]
________________________________

Matrix 4x4 :
    [1 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,]
    [2 ,0 ,3 ,0 ,]
    [297 ,59 ,10 ,0 ,]
    [1564489376 ,32593 ,1979723792 ,21998 ,]
```

---

I also tried returning a pointer instead of Mat struct , and then made a new Matrix using this pointer and it didn't work , I would like to know how this could be fixed without allocating dynamic memory with functions like malloc() calloc()  thanks :)

by the way I'm using Ubuntu on virtual machine if this connected somehow

Comment: Sorry to say but that code is really poorly written. It's pretty much unreadable. At a minimum, format it to be readable - don't put whole blocks of code on a single line, add spacing between blocks of code and functions, use descriptive variable names and not single letters everywhere.

Comment: remove all those function headers and other unnecessary `/`es , if possible try to improve the post by adding comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MatrixMultiplication` function, the array `q` is allocated on the stack. So at function exit, its memory is freed and matrix datas may be replaced with other values. The solution is to allocate memory with `malloc` so it is kept even outside of the function.

From your code, I just removed the variable `q` and replace `ptr` with a memory allocation :

```
Mat MatrixMultiplication (Mat a,Mat b){
int * ptr = malloc(a.rows * b.cols * sizeof(*ptr));
ArrayRandomizer(ptr,a.rows*b.cols,0,0);
Mat c = MatrixBuilder (ptr,a.rows,b.cols);
for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < b.cols; j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < a.cols; k++){
            setMatrixValueOfCell((MatrixValueOfCell(c,i,j)+(MatrixValueOfCell(a,i,k)*MatrixValueOfCell(b,k,j))),c,i,j);}}}

printf("\n________________________________\nDirect From Function :");
PrintMatrix(c);
printf("________________________________\n");
return c;

}
```

Beware also that the this code just to point out the problem you exposed. It can't be a global solution because it leads to another problem : memory leak.